# How Can GetElement From This Code

Tags: javascript, android, getelementbyid, basic4android

I'm using Basic4Android, and I want to get elements from this code.
This is my site code:

```
<li class='ff-item-type-1'>
    <img src='/templates/smartphone/images/sima/95x95xdo-min.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Qay8bs1PQM.webp' alt='Two Channel' title='Pla Tow Channel' width='95px' height='95px' class='mCS_img_loaded'><span>Tow Chanell</span>
    <a class='chanelllist' href='#tv2' title='Pla Tow Channel' onclick='playme('tv2')'>Show</a>
</li>
```

I want click In (Pla Tow Channel) With A Button on App.

I wrote this code:

```
WebViewExtras1.executeJavascript(WebView1,"document.getElementByclass('ff-item-type-1').click('playme('tv2')');")
```

But it's not working and I receive this error on log:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in null (Line: 1)

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Sorry , please help me.

Comment: I don't know anything about basic4android but you probably need to escape your inner `'`'s. Change this: `click('playme('tv2')')` to `click('playme(\'tv2\')')`.

Comment: Thank You But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `evaluteJavascript()` to inject JS codes from Java side to JS  side in the `WebView`.

```
mWebView.evaluateJavascript("JS codes");
```

However this method was introduced in Kit Kat (4.4.). Prior to Kit Kat you should use this code:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:JS codes");
```

So, you should have something like this:

```
String jsCodes = "";

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    mWebView.evaluateJavascript(jsCodes);
} else {
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsCodes);
}
```

The JavaScript code you should pass would be something like this:

```
document.getElementById('id_of_the_link').click();
```

**Note:** You would need to assign a ID to the `a` element of interest. If you can't do this, alternatively you can use `querySelector()` method.

```
document.querySelector('.ff-item-type-1 a').click();
```